# mongodb query in waterline,sailsjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Because it is a lot of code, I don't want to ask for details what is wrong, but want to ask about review what can be changed in **approach** to this.

This is controller that make query:

- It grabs data within time range
- Does aggregation so I get sum of some fields
- Because there are some fields from different collections i.e `leader_name`, I do other queries
- There is a `$in: workers` fragment in the `$match` part that also need `workers` to filter from a different query

```
getGroupInRange: function (req, gres) {

    console.log(req.params);

    Group.find({name: {$in: req.params.id.split(',')}})
      .populate('workers')
      .exec(function(err, found){

        if (err) return gres.serverError(err);

        var workers = [];

        found.forEach(function(x){
          x.workers.forEach(function(xx){
            workers.push(xx.id);
          });
        });

        workers = workers.map(function (x) {
          return new ObjectId(x);
        });



        Event.native(function(err, collection) {
          if (err) return gres.serverError(err);

          var query = [
            {
              $match:
              {
                probe_time:
                {
                  $gte: new Date(req.params.from),
                  $lt: new Date(req.params.to)
                },
                worker_id:
                {
                  $in: workers
                }
              }
            },
            {
              $group:
              {
                _id:{worker_id:"$worker_id", group:"$group"},
                "total_logged_time":{$sum: "$duration"},
                "total_break_time":{$sum: {$cond: [ {$eq:["$user.work_mode", 'break']},"$duration", 0] }},
                "total_nonidle_duration":{$sum: {$cond: [ {$eq:["$user.presence", 'active']},"$duration", 0] }},
                "total_idle_time":{$sum: {$cond: [ {$eq:["$user.presence", 'idle']},"$duration", 0] }},
                "total_pro_apps_time":{$sum: {$cond: [ {$eq:["$app_category", 'productive']},"$duration", 0] }},
                "total_nonpro_apps_time":{$sum: {$cond: [ {$ne:["$app_category", 'productive']},"$duration", 0] }},
                "status1":{$sum: {$cond: [ {$eq:["$user.work_mode", 'CUSTOM_1']},"$duration", 0] }},
                "status2":{$sum: {$cond: [ {$eq:["$user.work_mode", 'CUSTOM_2']},"$duration", 0] }},
                "status3":{$sum: {$cond: [ {$eq:["$user.work_mode", 'CUSTOM_3']},"$duration", 0] }},
                "status4":{$sum: {$cond: [ {$eq:["$user.work_mode", 'CUSTOM_4']},"$duration", 0] }},

                "leader_name":{$last:"$leader_name"},
              }
            },
            {
              $project:
              {
                "total_logged_time":1,
                "total_break_time":1,
                "total_nonidle_duration":1,
                "total_idle_time":1,
                "total_pro_apps_time": 1,
                "total_nonpro_apps_time" : 6388,
                "print_qty":1,
                "medium_print_qty":1,
                "medium_download_size":1,
                "effectivity":1,
                "status1":1,
                "status2":1,
                "medium_break_time": { $multiply:[3600, {$divide:["$total_break_time", "$total_logged_time"]} ] },
                "worker_name":"$_id.worker_id",
                "leader_name":1
              }
            },
            {
              $group:
              {
                _id:"$_id.group",
                data:{$push: "$$ROOT"}
              }
            }
          ];


          collection.aggregate(query).toArray(function (err, results) {
            if (err) return res.serverError(err);

            Worker.find({_id:{$in: workers}})
              .populate('leader')
              .exec(function (err, res) {

                results.map(function(x,y){
                  x.data.map(function (xx, yy) {

                    xx.leader_name = res.filter(function (x) {
                      return xx._id.worker_id.equals(x.id);
                    })[0].leader.fullname;

                  })
                });


                return gres.ok(results);
              });

          });
        });

      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should fix your indentation and styling, I would use a tool like [JSFiddle's Tidy](http://jsfiddle.net/) function to clean up your code.

---

### `err`:

The word you're looking for is `error`, no need to sacrifice readability for two characters.

> ```
> .exec(function(err, found) {
> ```

---

### Overriding `err`/`error`:

In the following code block, you overwrite the parameter `err` or `error`, this is bad practice, it'd be better off named something like `error_two`.

> ```
>           collection.aggregate(query).toArray(function(error, results) {
>               if (error) return res.serverError(error);
>
>               Worker.find({
>                       _id: {
>                           $in: workers
>                       }
>                   })
>                   .populate('leader')
>                   .exec(function(error, res) {
> ```

In fact, you actually overwrite it three times!

---

### Overriding `x`:

You override `x` in the following code block:

You should apply the same as before and name it `xxx` or something (because `xx` is already existent)

> ```
> results.map(function(x, y) {
>     x.data.map(function(xx, yy) {
>
>         xx.leader_name = res.filter(function(x) {
> ```

---

## `y`:

In the above point's code, you never actually use `y`, as it is the second parameter, it can be entirely removed, JavaScript does not require an explicit amount of parameters.

---

### In total:

In total, it would look like:

```
getGroupInRange: function(req, gres) {

    console.log(req.params);

    Group.find({
        name: {
            $in: req.params.id.split(',')
        }
    })
    .populate('workers')
    .exec(function(error, found) {
        if (error) return gres.serverError(error);
            var workers = [];
            found.forEach(function(x) {
                x.workers.forEach(function(xx) {
                    workers.push(xx.id);
                });
            });
            workers = workers.map(function(x) {
                return new ObjectId(x);
            });

            Event.native(function(error, collection) {
                if (error) return gres.serverError(error);

                var query = [{
                    $match: {
                        probe_time: {
                            $gte: new Date(req.params.from),
                            $lt: new Date(req.params.to)
                        },
                        worker_id: {
                            $in: workers
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    $group: {
                        _id: {
                            worker_id: "$worker_id",
                            group: "$group"
                        },
                        "total_logged_time": {
                            $sum: "$duration"
                        },
                        "total_break_time": {
                            $sum: {
                                $cond: [{
                                    $eq: ["$user.work_mode", 'break']
                                }, "$duration", 0]
                            }
                        },
                        "total_nonidle_duration": {
                            $sum: {
                                $cond: [{
                                    $eq: ["$user.presence", 'active']
                                }, "$duration", 0]
                            }
                        },
                        "total_idle_time": {
                            $sum: {
                                $cond: [{
                                    $eq: ["$user.presence", 'idle']
                                }, "$duration", 0]
                            }
                        },
                        "total_pro_apps_time": {
                            $sum: {
                                $cond: [{
                                    $eq: ["$app_category", 'productive']
                                }, "$duration", 0]
                            }
                        },
                        "total_nonpro_apps_time": {
                            $sum: {
                                $cond: [{
                                    $ne: ["$app_category", 'productive']
                                }, "$duration", 0]
                            }
                        },
                        "status1": {
                            $sum: {
                                $cond: [{
                                    $eq: ["$user.work_mode", 'CUSTOM_1']
                                }, "$duration", 0]
                            }
                        },
                        "status2": {
                            $sum: {
                                $cond: [{
                                    $eq: ["$user.work_mode", 'CUSTOM_2']
                                }, "$duration", 0]
                            }
                        },
                        "status3": {
                            $sum: {
                                $cond: [{
                                    $eq: ["$user.work_mode", 'CUSTOM_3']
                                }, "$duration", 0]
                            }
                        },
                        "status4": {
                            $sum: {
                                $cond: [{
                                    $eq: ["$user.work_mode", 'CUSTOM_4']
                                }, "$duration", 0]
                            }
                        },

                        "leader_name": {
                            $last: "$leader_name"
                        },
                    }
                }, {
                    $project: {
                        "total_logged_time": 1,
                        "total_break_time": 1,
                        "total_nonidle_duration": 1,
                        "total_idle_time": 1,
                        "total_pro_apps_time": 1,
                        "total_nonpro_apps_time": 6388,
                        "print_qty": 1,
                        "medium_print_qty": 1,
                        "medium_download_size": 1,
                        "effectivity": 1,
                        "status1": 1,
                        "status2": 1,
                        "medium_break_time": {
                            $multiply: [3600, {
                                $divide: ["$total_break_time", "$total_logged_time"]
                            }]
                        },
                        "worker_name": "$_id.worker_id",
                        "leader_name": 1
                    }
                }, {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$_id.group",
                        data: {
                            $push: "$$ROOT"
                        }
                    }
                }];


                collection.aggregate(query).toArray(function(error_two, results) {
                    if (error_two) return res.serverError(error_two);

                    Worker.find({
                        _id: {
                            $in: workers
                        }
                    })
                    .populate('leader')
                    .exec(function(error_three, res) {
                        results.map(function(x) {
                            x.data.map(function(xx) {
                                xx.leader_name = res.filter(function(xxx) {
                                    return xx._id.worker_id.equals(xxx.id);
                                })[0].leader.fullname;
                            })
                        });
                        return gres.ok(results);
                    });
            });
        });
    });
}
```